# Matching with regular expressions in R

Tags: r, regex

suppose I have the next data frame.

```
table<-data.frame(col1=c("4-p","4-p 1.0","2-p","4-p 1.6","2-p 1.0"),col2=c("4-p 1.0","2-p 1.0","1.6 2-p","4-p 1.8","1.0 2-p civic"), p_ok=c("Y","N","Y","Y","Y"), n_ok=c("N","Y","N","N","Y"))

    col1          col2 p_ok n_ok
     4-p       4-p 1.0    Y    N
 4-p 1.0       2-p 1.0    N    Y
     2-p       1.6 2-p    Y    N
 4-p 1.6       4-p 1.8    Y    N
 2-p 1.0 1.0 2-p civic    Y    Y
```

And a I have to implement a method to determinate if the columns are similar or not (p_ok and n_ok).

The rules would be, if the number plus "-p" from column 1 is equal to col2, p_ok is 'Y', else 'N'. If the other number (1.0, 1.6, 1.8), is the same in both columns, n_ok is 'Y'. Notice that the order in the string can change (look at row 5).

Bear in mind that the real data contains multiple variants of the data (2-p, 3-p, 4-p, 5-p) and (1.0,2.0,......) so regular expressions would be necessary to determinate if the columns are similar or not (p_ok and n_ok).

The rules would be, if the number plus "-p" from column 1 is equal to col2, p_ok is 'Y', else 'N'. If the other number (1.0, 1.6, 1.8), is the same in both columns, n_ok is 'Y'.
Bear in mind that the real data contains multiple variantes of the data (2-p, 3-p, 4-p, 5-p) and (1.0,2.0,......) so regular expressions would be necessary in this exercise.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by switching the order of the 'p' substring and numbers using `sub`, then for elements that don't have numbers replace it with 0, split the string into two using `strsplit` and `Reduce` it to a logical `matrix` by comparing the `list` of `matrices`.  If needed, we can replace the logical matrix with `Y/N`

```
res <- Reduce(`==`, lapply(table[1:2], function(x) do.call(rbind, 
       strsplit(sub("^([A-z0-9-]+)\\b$", "\\1 0", 
        sub("^([0-9.]+)\\s+([0-9]+-p).*", "\\2 \\1", x)), " "))))
ifelse(res, "Y", "N")
#   [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "Y"  "N" 
#[2,] "N"  "Y" 
#[3,] "Y"  "N" 
#[4,] "Y"  "N" 
#[5,] "Y"  "Y"
```

Comment: Yes, is partially ok, but be carefult that the columns no always are distributed in the same way, for instance, row 5 (n_ok is 'Y'), not 'N' because de 1.0 is located at the beginning of the string